# filtering nested dataframe (list column) over values in list with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataframe including a list column. I want to filter this (nested) list column (`data`, containing a dataframe) on its contained column `unit` with the values contained in another list (`x`). I think I am quite close, the problem is I don't succeed to 'convert' list `x` into a vector for the filter statement. Greatful for any hint!

```
library(tidyverse)
```

the dataframe:

```
df<- structure(list(data = list(structure(list(unit = c("A1", "A2"
), value = c("10", "10")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("unit", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -2L)), structure(list(
  unit = c("B1", "B2", "A1"), value = c("10", "10", "10")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("unit", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                       -3L)), structure(list(unit = c("C1", "B2"), value = c("10", "10"
                                                                                                                                       )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("unit", 
                                                                                                                                                                            "value"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))), x = list(c("A1", "A2"), c("B1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "B2"), "C1")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -3L), .Names = c("data", "x"))
```

This works only if `x` has only one element:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(y=map(data, ~filter(., unit %in% x)))
```

`flatten_chr` creates a vector including the values contained in `x` of all (!) rows, not for list per row.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(y=map(data, ~filter(., unit %in% flatten_chr(x))))
```

The critical issues seems to be how can I convert `x` into a vector per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map2()` instead to iterate over `data` and `x` in parallel, i.e. row-wise.

```
df %>%
  mutate(y= map2(data, x, ~ filter(..1, unit %in% ..2))) # using ..1/..2 instead of .x/.y, to avoid confusion 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  data             x         y               
  <list>           <list>    <list>          
1 <tibble [2 × 2]> <chr [2]> <tibble [2 × 2]>
2 <tibble [3 × 2]> <chr [2]> <tibble [2 × 2]>
3 <tibble [2 × 2]> <chr [1]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

In this pattern you don't need `flatten_chr()` anymore since `x`/`..2` is already a character object inside of the mapping function.